# Spit the string and pick the right values (Bigquery)

Tags: google-bigquery

[Query table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0u4d.png)

I have 2 tables in the picture attached, top shows the actually data. I would like to query it in the bottom table format. I am using big query to perform this. Please advice

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please edit your question to show a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You can also read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Thank you Mikhail,

Comment: 'code' SELECT
  timestamp,
  #__key__.path,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(__key__.path,r'"([^"]+)"') AS hostname,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(__key__.path,r'"([^"^"^"]+)"') AS machine,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(__key__.path,r'"([^"^"^"]+)"') AS variable,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(__key__.path,r'"([^"^"^"]+)"') AS id,
  IF(value.provided = 'integer', CAST(value.integer AS STRING), CAST(value.boolean AS STRING)) AS value,
FROM
  [operating-surge-152315:spark_stamping_press.Press_data_2]
LIMIT
  10

Comment: you can update your original question by adding that code

Comment: Please excuse my formatting.. I am still trying to figure out on posting question sat stackoverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below

```
#legacySQL
SELECT
  TimeStamp,
  Value_provided,
  IF(value_provided = 'integer', CAST(value_integer AS STRING), CAST(value_boolean AS STRING)) AS value,
  __key__app AS ProjectID,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(__key__path, r'".*?"[, ]*"(.*?)"') AS hostname, 
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(__key__path, r'(?:".*?"[, ]*){3}"(.*?)"') AS machine, 
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(__key__path, r'(?:".*?"[, ]*){5}"(.*?)"') AS variable
FROM [operating-surge-152315:spark_stamping_press.Press_data_2]
```

From the other hand - I think using positioning is not safe. Below is name-based approach

```
#legacySQL
SELECT
  TimeStamp,
  Value_provided,
  IF(value_provided = 'integer', CAST(value_integer AS STRING), CAST(value_boolean AS STRING)) AS value,
  __key__app AS ProjectID,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(__key__path, r'"hostname"[, ]*"(.*?)"') AS hostname,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(__key__path, r'"machine"[, ]*"(.*?)"') AS machine,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(__key__path, r'"variable"[, ]*"(.*?)"') AS variable
FROM [operating-surge-152315:spark_stamping_press.Press_data_2]
```

Comment: Exactly how I need, Thank you very much for your guidance. I was able to do the other tables too on the same way

Comment: `SELECT
  #Timestamp,
  STRFTIME_UTC_USEC(TimeStamp,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") AS TimeStamp,
  Value.provided,
    __key__.app AS ProjectID,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(__key__.path, r'"hostname"[, ]*"(.*?)"') AS hostname,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(__key__.path, r'"machine"[, ]*"(.*?)"') AS machine,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(__key__.path, r'"variable"[, ]*"(.*?)"') AS variable,
  IF(value.provided = 'integer', CAST(value.integer AS STRING), CAST(value.boolean AS STRING)) AS value
FROM [spark-test-project-152415:spark_machine_learning.spark_12272016]
ORDER BY TimeStamp
LIMIT 100000`

Comment: I am running the above query,  The Variable column contains multiple dimensions.. I need to split them to multiple dimensions(Columns).. I think I need to write up a sub query to it.. Could you please help me on how to start this.

Comment: no problem. comments are not tailored for questions/answers though - please post new question so we will be able to answer

Comment: Okay I will, Thank you

Comment: please make sure you provide example of input data and expected output

Answer (score 0):

To help get you started, I think you'll want something like this:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  IF(value_provided = 'integer', CAST(value_integer AS STRING), CAST(value_boolean AS STRING)) AS value,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(__key___path, r'"([^"]+)"')[OFFSET(5)] AS variable
FROM MyTable;
```

Edit: If you want to select elements of the result of `REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL` as top level columns, you can use a subselect:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  IF(value_provided = 'integer', CAST(value_integer AS STRING), CAST(value_boolean AS STRING)) AS value,
  keys[OFFSET(0)] AS hostname,
  keys[OFFSET(5)] AS variable
FROM (
  SELECT *,
    REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(__key___path, r'"([^"]+)"') AS keys
  FROM MyTable
);
```

This example selects just the first and sixth elements, but you could include whichever you like.

Comment: Thank you Eliott, It really helped me.. I was able to get to the following query,

Comment: SELECT
  timestamp,
  #__key__.path,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(__key__.path,r'"([^"]+)"') AS hostname,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(__key__.path,r'"([^"^"^"]+)"') AS machine,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(__key__.path,r'"([^"^"^"]+)"') AS variable,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(__key__.path,r'"([^"^"^"]+)"') AS id,
  IF(value.provided = 'integer', CAST(value.integer AS STRING), CAST(value.boolean AS STRING)) AS value,
FROM
  [operating-surge-152315:spark_stamping_press.Press_data_2]
LIMIT
  10

Comment: I am still not sure how to extract the 2nd, 4th, 6th and 8th part of the string.. and place it under the attribute names hostname, machines, variable, integer, variabe

Comment: Please excuse my formatting.. I am still trying to figure out on posting question sat stackoverflow

Comment: 'code' Error: Encountered " "AS" "AS "" at line 15, column 19. Was expecting: <EOF>. Also I got another error of using EXTRACT_ALL.. I am currently using Big query and I think it currently does not support EXTRACT_ALL

Comment: You are missing the `#standardSQL` part at the beginning to enable standard SQL.

Comment: __italic__ Got it now, Thanks Elliott